# xdebug.file_link_format for PhpStorm and WSL2

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm using PhpStorm, Docker and WSL2 on Windows 10. My project files are stored under `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04\home\me\www\project`.

I found out, that I can configure xdebug to make files clickable in order to be opened in PhpStorm.

The correct format in order to work is this:
`jetbrains://php-storm/navigate/reference?project=project&path=/docker/nginx/Dockerfile:3`

In my xdebug.ini I have this:
`xdebug.file_link_format='jetbrains://php-storm/navigate/reference?project=project&path=%f:%l'`

`%f` renders to `/var/www/html/docker/nginx/Dockerfile`, since the first three folders are the location inside the docker container.

Is it possible to ommit the `/var/www/html` part somehow? Couldn't find any options.

Some kind of path mapping would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I filed a bug with PhpStorm about their `path` opening feature not respecting path mappings: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-69488/IDE-Remote-Control-Use-PHP-Server-mappings-to-open-file-links

Unfortunately it seems they have removed this from 2022.3 (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-308020/Opening-a-file-via-API-api-file-does-not-work-anymore-in-PhpStorm-2022.3), and you now need to install a plugin.

I haven't tested whether the new plugin has the same issue yet.

Comment: Thanks, @Derick.  

But I already had that plugin installed, and it works if the url is correct.  

Problem is, that xdebug writes an absolute path to `%f`.  

So in the example above, instead of `/var/www/html/docker/nginx/Dockerfile` I need `docker/nginx/Dockerfile`.  

So basically it would be super nice if there was an extra option to declare a path mapping when using `xdebug.file_link_format`. Unfortunately I don't see that possibility in PhpStorm.  

BTW: great work with xdebug, it's still a big part of my developing life :)

Comment: I have a ticket open to do path mappings on the Xdebug side: https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=2099